# Como deletar User utilizando Parse (Erro: insufficient auth to delete user )

Tags: android, parse.com

Olá, estou criando um app utilizando o Parse para salvar dados no Heroku. Estou com uma dificuldade para deletar Usuários. Consigo deletar objetos de outras coleções com o comando:

```
objeto.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
           Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Exercicio removido.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
  });
```

Mas quando se trata de deletar Users, não funciona. Deixa o ParseException e com o valor de insufficient auth to delete user.  Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: [Apenas o próprio usuário ou a masterKey podem excluir o usuário.](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/3228)

Comment: Você pode utilizar `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` para usar a *masterKey*.

Comment: Tem como você me mostrar um exemplo? Eu vi isso em alguns foruns e tentei colocar isso lá, mas ele exibe erro quando coloco o ".Cloud" ele pergunta se quero criar uma variável ou coisas semelhantes. Poderia me ajudar me mostrando em um exemplo?